# How to make a phone call from a list view in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a list of peoples names and each is linked with a certain phone number from a JSON database. I am trying to make it so that every time they are clicked, it will call their number. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Button;




import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;



    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> legislatorList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        legislatorList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
   new GetLegislators().execute();

}
```

Comment: Try using proper Java language inside an Android app. Android Studio is just an IDE, thus cannot even run on your mobile phone, what to say about making phone calls....

Answer (score 0):

Request Permission in manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

For calling use this code on listView itemClick.

```
private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listViewUsers.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            User user = userList.get(position);
            String newNumber;
            newNumber = user.getPhone();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + newNumber));// Initiates the Intent
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

This how you dial from listView, but you can also call directly.